# Android Auto Update doesnt work

Tags: android, google-play-services, auto-update, google-play-console

I've just launch my first android app  (about a week ago), and it almost has 1000 downloads. 
I've been talking to a couple of people that downloaded the app, and they all have the auto update option turned on in playstore. None of them reveive any kinda of notificatin or the app doesnt upgrate itself.
Is there any setting that can change this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a number of things that you can check,

1. Check whether you have the latest version displayed as the current version in Google developer console.
2. Check whether the latest update is rolled out to 100% of users (Play store now supports staged rollout). This can be verified from the release management section.
3. Did you add any new permissions to your updated version? This requires manual intervention in the case of auto-updates.
4. Did you change anything in the manifest file which affects devices that can install the app? For example, if you have added telephony features in the update, devices without that feature won't get the update.

Lastly note that usually auto updates are triggered only when the user is in a Wifi network.

Comment: I did 3 and 4. What should I do now?

Comment: There is nothing that you need to do. Anyone who can continue to access your app will get a notification that they have an update available. They just need to review the update and approve it.